# How to capture enter key in html and redirect to asp page?

Tags: javascript, html

in my plain HTML page, i had a textbox for user to input keyword and then redirect to asp page.
i use javascript to capture keywords when user click submit button.

but when user press enter, the HTML page will reload and return error page.
how can i capture enter key event ? so that it will redirect to asp page.
thanks

my javascript code as follows:

```
function searching() {            
            var keywordsStr = document.getElementById('keywords').value;
            var cmd = "http://xxx/SearchEngine/Searching.aspx?keywords=" + encodeURI(keywordsStr) ;
            window.open(cmd);
        }
```

my html code as follow:

```
   <form name="form1" method="post" action="" >
     <input name="keywords" type="text" id="keywords" size="50" >
     <input type="submit" name="btn_search" id="btn_search" value="Search" onClick="javascript:searching(); return false;">
     <input type="reset" name="btn_reset" id="btn_reset" value="Reset">
   </form>
```

Comment: I've created [a JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/bfuxx/) based on your *exact* code, and it works without issue (although you will get redirected to a pron site due to your replacement domain name). Are you sure `searching()` is available as a function? Have you tried using something like [Firebug for Firefox](http://getfirebug.com) or the developer tools in IE and Chrome (F5 in each)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your 'action' attribute is empty, which means the HTML page will post to itself (reloading basically). You need to put the URL of your ASP page in there to be able to post the data.

```
 <form name="form1" method="get" action="http://xxx/SearchEngine/Searching.aspx">
     <input name="keywords" type="text" size="50" >
     <input type="submit" name="btn_search" value="Search">
     <input type="reset" name="btn_reset" value="Reset">
 </form>
```

and you might want to change the method to `method="get"` to mimic your javascript function.
If you want the submit to create a new window, you can add a target attribute to the form:

```
target="_blank"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to using `jquery`,

You can do something like,

```
$("#keywords").keyup(function(e){
   if(e.keyCode == '13')
   {
       //enter key
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just open your form's result in a new window?
I prefer to use post:

```
<form action="http://xxx/SearchEngine/Searching.aspx" method="post" target="_blank">
```

but you can use a get call, as you did in your snippet

```
<form action="http://xxx/SearchEngine/Searching.aspx" method="get" target="_blank">
```

If you **really** want to detect the enter key .. in your case I would suggest you to use onkeydown event to the whole page to prevent to fire events associated with the enter key (eg submit your form), by using:

```
document.onkeydown = checkKeycode
function checkKeycode(e) 
{
    var keycode;
    if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    else if (e) keycode = e.which;
    // alert("keycode: " + keycode);
    if (keycode == 13)
    {
        alert('enter key is pressed: now do something');
    }
}
```